# How to replace specific numbers with specific text?

Tags: excel, search, replace, excel-formula, match

I'm trying to sort through 40,000 addresses that show only a "county code," which I'm trying to convert into the word of the actual county itself. I have a masterlist that matches each county with a unique code. How can I replace the county codes with words efficiently?

Example: my spreadsheet shows "356" as the county code. From my master list, I know that code corresponds to Richmond county. How can I correct all 40,000 county codes into the text equivalent?

Comment: Look into [VLOOKUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808932/using-vlookup#30609594)

Comment: INDEX() with MATCH() will also work

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vlookup(), COmbination of Match() and Index(), Combination of Match() and Offset(). Use any of the three you must get result. If any doubt let me know.